# How to implement LSTM autoencoders on time series data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, anomaly-detection

The below Keras blog mentions at a high level about LSTM autoencoders.

https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

But only a barebone reference code is given & its incomplete.

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
```

**Questions**

1. How can I expand the above code and develop a working code for some dummy time series data ?

Comment: Do you want to find anomalies "along" the series (with position) or just "yes, this series is abnormal"?

Comment: And is there any special reason to want an `autoencoder` instead of just a model that finds anomalies?

Comment: Assume for example that data is at a sampling frequency of 15 minutes. I want datetime point at which anomalies occur.

Comment: What model are you referring to?

Comment: Any model. My question is: "does it need to be an `autoencoder`"? (An autoencoder has the goal of recreating the input data as a smaller condensed unintelligible data for further usage in other models.)

Comment: Yes I am interested in autoencoder specially

Comment: You understand that autoencoders do not detect anything, right? Can you explain how you want to use it in details?